# On page reload, show form as long as its on selection

Tags: javascript

So I'm using the below code to show/hide portions on my form:

```
document.getElementById('res').addEventListener('change', function() {
    if (this.value !== 'PA') {
        formWrapperState.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        formWrapperState.style.display = 'block';
    }
});
```

Sometimes, when I test my form and I reload the page and it lands on 'California', the form is hidden until I change to another state and then back to California.

How can I make it show the form whenever 'CA' is present, even on page reload?

Comment: Are you waiting for the page to load before running your code? You probably need to post more code for context.

Comment: So on load, it loads on `Choose..`, then on 'Change' like the script shows, it applied alerts/shows the form. I wanted to see if I can show the form 'on load' if CA is present/selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only firing your function when the dropdown changes. You also need to run it when the page loads, something like:

```
var field = document.getElementById('resident');
function handler() {
    if (field.value !== 'CA') {
        formWrapperState.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        formWrapperState.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
field.addEventListener('change', handler);
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', handler);
handler(); // for good measure
```

Comment: Thanks so much - Works like a charm.